# using length function in REGEXP_REPLACE() in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am removing that last 3 characters from the string "ABC123" using `regexp_replace` function in Oracle using the below statement

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC123','123','', LENGTH('ABC123') - 3) from dual;
```

The same result can be achieved in Postgres with the below statements,

```
select regexp_replace('ABC123','[123]', '','g')
select translate('ABC123','123', '');
```

Is there any way I can use the length function for replace as I have used in Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use `left()`?

```
select left('ABC123', length('ABC123') - 3)
```

The same idea can be used in Oracle as well, but you need to use the `substr()` function.  This should be more efficient in both databases.

Comment: I Suppose it works similar to LTRIM function defined in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into the trim functionality.
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/

"select REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC123','123','', LENGTH('ABC123') - 3) from dual;"
would become
select ltrim('ABC123','ABC') from dual;
resulting in 123